# How to assign a value to the i-th member of an ordered list?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In set theory, we can write the following notation: $\;S'=S\cup\{\text{value}\}$

Now let $\;S=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\;$ be an ordered list of $n$ pairwise distinct elements

How to define $S'$ equals to $S$ after assigning a $\text{value}$ to the $i^\text{th}$ ordered member of $S\;$?

It will be helpful if you add a complete example to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In set theory, we can write the following notation:
>   $\;S'=S\cup\{value\}$

Yes, we can. However one would most often not write “value” but rather introduce a new variable or constant, e.g. $v$. Note that if $v$ was an element of $S$ that $S‘$ would be equal to $S$.

> Now let $\;S=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\;$ be an ordered list of $n$ pairwise
>   distinct elements

This is called a $n$-tuple.

> How to define $S'$ equals to $S$ after assigning a $value$ to the
>   $i^{th}$ ordered member of $S\;$?

You defined $S$ already with $a_i$ as the $i$-th component. This is now bound to $S$. You can not reassign it.

You seem to want another
$$
S’ = (a_1’, \dotsc, a_n’)
$$
where $a_j’ = a_j$ for all $j \ne i$ and $a_i’= v$. Again if $v$ was equal to $a_i$ then $S‘$ would be equal to $S$.

Comment: Yes, but where is the assigned "$value$" in your answer? could you write the line of defining $S'$ after the $i^{th}$ member changed to $value$, please?

Comment: There is nothing changing. The use of the equal sign iin the sense of the usual mathematics is either as equality relation or as initial assignment. But not as redefinition like the destructive update of an imperative programming language. Have a look at a functional programming language and how they handle tuple / list operations.

Comment: The usual style there is to introduce new variables, like here the $S’$, which is defined building on prior data, like most components of $S$, just maybe different in the $i$-th component, while $S$ keeps its values.

Comment: Actually you are right, I'm writing a pseudocode but in a mathematician way.

Comment: Take $x := x + 1$, where I used $:=$ to emphasize the definition aspect of the equal sign. This makes sense if you have the changing variables of an imperative programming language, but the usage in mathematics as $x = x + 1$ would imply $0 = 1$, a false statement, because the $x$ on the lhs and rhs are considered to be the same.

Comment: Is it good to write $S'=(a_1', ..., a_n')$ where $a_j' \leftarrow a_j\;;\quad$ then write $\quad a_i'\leftarrow v$ ?

Comment: For me it would be ok, lets wait if there are other opinions.

Answer (score 0):

If for example, L = (a,b,c,d) is an ordered list and the
value 3 is assigned to b (b = 3), then L = (a,3,c,d).